# WebSocket Get Futures Realtime Price Binance

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

This is how I established a real-time price WebSocket price for Spot Market, but how do I get the real-time price for Futures BTCUSDT?

```
socket = f"wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/dotusdt@kline_1m"

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_close(ws):
    print("Connection closed")

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_message=on_message, on_close=on_close)
```

Looked for answers but couldn't find any favorable ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

socket = f"wss://fstream.binance.com:9443/ws/dotusdt@kline_1m"

you need to add "f" before "stream"

Answer (score 0):

Add 'f' before 'stream' and remove the ':9443